# Need assistance in firebase rules

Tags: firebase

Currently, I have implemented a project folder structure similar to the below
I have added the Phone authentication in my code.

Project folder structure

[image]

Now with the help of Firebase rules, I restricted my users to access only authenticated phone number folder

Here is the Firebase rules Implemented

[image]

With the above rules, admin able to read and write the data.

But, now problem coming for Suppliers, since they have logged in their phone number and it is different than Admin number, hence they are not able to access the Admin phone number folder.

Could you suggest me to improve the rules here?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, it is not necessary to have the user_id at two levels, one is enough.
I think what you need is the following

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$admin_ID": {
        ".read": "$admin_ID === auth.uid"
        ".write": "$admin_ID === auth.uid"
              "$supplier_id": {
              ".read": "$supplier_id === auth.uid"
              ".write": "$supplier_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```